# How to center alight content in a div with knowing the height of both parent & child

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have product items to display like this [image]

Now the challenge for me here is vertically middle aligning the text in first & third column, whereas the text in the middle column can increase or decrease reasonably, but i have to keep the content in the left & right column always vertically middle aligned.

e.g here is the code

```
<div class="product">
  <div class="title">My Test Title</div>
  <div class="price">
    From<br/>
    $2500
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et blanditiis, quibusdam commodi beatae, dolorum reiciendis, ex veniam esse recusandae iusto sapiente labore quisquam illo deserunt odio non magni velit! Sed.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et blanditiis, quibusdam commodi beatae, dolorum reiciendis, ex veniam esse recusandae iusto sapiente labore quisquam illo deserunt odio non magni velit! Sed.</p>
  </div>
</div>

// AND THE CSS is 
.product {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.product > div {
  padding : 10px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.title
{
  width : 120px;
  float:left;
}
.price {
  width:120px;
  float:right;
  text-align:right;
}
.description {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/exleedo/rexwya5e/

Is there a way to do that without using as `display:table-cell;` or using javscript to find the height of the parent ?

The reason with using table-cell is because table-cell won't take width anymore from css, and using JS to calculate the height of the parent is not very great I think.

Comment: @Paulie_D sorry Paulie, my bad. I have added a simple fiddle now. I have already have the solution for using display:table-cell; and using js to calculate the height of the parent, but its the curiosity for a more simple solution that make me ask this question.

Comment: The answer basically..is NO. CSS can't align elements in different containers.

Comment: Flexbox can make the containers equal height, it can even center the contents BUT it still can't align things between containers.

Comment: thanks @Paulie_D , I think I am gonna go with the table-cell option. I thought about it again, and I had this one issue of width with display:table-cell, but I can assign width to a div inside a table-cell div. I guess thats perfect. I will add the fiddle in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am gonna go with display:table-cell; because that seems the most appropriate one for me. The reason I didn't go with this before is that I was trying to assign width to the table-column div, which is not correct. Now I have add a div inside table-column and assign width there which solves my concern.

e.g here is the code :

```
<div class="table product">
  <div class="table-column">
    <div class="title">
      The Title
    </div></div>
    <div class="table-column">
      <div class="description">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro fugit vero non dolorum, nisi modi veritatis ipsum magni, praesentium blanditiis vel error, odit dolores atque culpa, ratione tempore iusto neque. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-column">
      <div class="price">
        Price
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

// And the CSS

/* Start : CSS Table*/
.table .table-column {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.table .table-column.align-top {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.table .table-column.align-bottom {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.table .table-column.padding-left-10px {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.table .table-column.padding-right-15px {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.table .table-column.padding-right-20px {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.table .table-column.padding-right-40px {
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.table .table-column.no-paddings {
  padding: 0px;
}

.table .table-column.full {
  width: 100%;
}
/* End : CSS Table*/

.product {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.product > div {
  padding : 10px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.title
{
  width : 120px;
  float:left;
}
.price {
  width:120px;
  float:right;
  text-align:right;
}
.description {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Check it in this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/exleedo/zL9arsj7/1/